# How do I rename a field in a structure array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, field, rename, matlab-struct

Given a structure array, how do I rename a field?  For example, given the following, how do I change "bar" to "baz".

```
clear
a(1).foo = 1;
a(1).bar = 'one';
a(2).foo = 2;
a(2).bar = 'two';
a(3).foo = 3;
a(3).bar = 'three';
disp(a)
```

What is the best method, where "best" is a balance of performance, clarity, and generality?

Comment: (MathWorks employees, see g560416.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expanding on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2733608/52738) from Matthew, you can also use [dynamic field names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) if the new and old field names are stored as strings:

```
newName = 'baz';
oldName = 'bar';
[a.(newName)] = a.(oldName);
a = rmfield(a,oldName);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it with list expansion/`rmfield`:

```
[a.baz] = a.bar;
a = rmfield(a,'bar');
disp(a)
```

The first line was originally written `[a(:).baz] = deal(a(:).bar);`, but SCFrench pointed out that the `deal` was unnecessary.

Comment: You don't need deal on the first line. You can just use [a.baz]=a.bar;

Comment: Even better! I'll modify this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a a way to do it with struct2cell/cell2struct:

```
f = fieldnames(a);
f{strmatch('bar',f,'exact')} = 'baz';
c = struct2cell(a);
a = cell2struct(c,f);
disp(a)
```

Comment: Function rmfield.m does exactly this. Regarding performance rmfield is very slow. Usually you do not need to rename field in structure.

Comment: I didn't realize that rmfield is implemented in MATLAB code. Yes, it's doing something very similar. Thanks for the pointer.